# Error in SAPUI5 Visual Editor in Adaptation Project in Business Application Studio

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

We are trying to extend the Import Supplier Invoices Fiori (F3041) app to disable the Post functionality in the app. The Post button on the first page can be hidden using UI Adaptation but for the Post button in the detail page's footer, we have created an Adaptation Project in Business Application Studio. Now, the below error is being returned when trying to navigate to the detail page from the initial page:

"Error occurred during navigation"

A relevant SAP Note https://me.sap.com/notes/0002845173 mentions that related business roles are required to be assigned to the user. The same issue in the S4 system's Fiori Launchpad was resolved by role assignment. But for the Adaptation project, even if the same roles are assigned to the communication user for BAS/BTP to the S4 system, the issue remains.

Please advice.